# Regex: match string with previous match

Tags: regex, pcre, grafana

I'm trying hard to resolve this regex puzzle but this is above my expertise...

I have strings like this:

String 1:

```
Interface123|HostVienna ~ Tunnel22 ~ CustomerA ~ ServiceA  ~ Vienna, Street 10|HostAmsterdam ~ Interface123 ~ CustomerB ~ ServiceA  ~ Amsterdam, Street 40|HostSarajevo ~ Interface12 ~ CustomerC ~ ServiceA ~ Sarajevo, Street 1040
```

String 2

```
Interface123|HostAmsterdam ~ Interface123 ~ CustomerB ~ ServiceA  ~ Amsterdam,Street 40
```

I'm trying to make one regex that can match everything from the beginning of the string until "|" (word) and using that match I'm trying to find the string delimited by "|" that contains that word.  In my examples, th word is `Interface123`.

From either example above, the result should be:

```
HostAmsterdam ~ Interface123 ~ CustomerB ~ ServiceA  ~ Amsterdam,Street 40
```

Is this possible with pure regex?

Comment: Your explanation and example arent the same. You said until the "|" but your example starts after it

Comment: What flavour of regex?

Comment: I need this for Grafana, i thing it is Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: Please tag your programming language / environment.

Comment: Should `Interface123` match a row containing `Interface1234`?

Comment: Will the search term ever be the first or last segment in a group?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with regexp back references, though not every implementation supports them.  Something like:

```
^([^|]+)\|(?:[^|]*\|)*?([^|]*\1[^|]*)
```

Second group will capture what you need.

Explanation: `^([^|]+)\|` captures your keyword, `(?:[^|]*\|)*?` matches zero or more strings surrounded by `'|'` not having keyword, `([^|]*\1[^|]*)` matches what you finally need.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Td8Adq/1)

Answer (score 1):

`/^([^|]+)\|(?:[^|]+\|)*?\K[^|]*\b\1\b[^|]*/`

It is important to capture the needle and at minimum use wordboundaries when searching for its next occurrence.

Also, it is important to enable a match as the first, middle or last data set in the string.  This is the importance of `(?:[^|]+\|)*?`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7lMwZf/5

Breakdown:

```
^                     # start of string
([^|]+)\|             # capture needle then match first delimiting pipe
(?:[^|]+\|)*?         # match zero or more "sets of data"
\K[^|]*\b\1\b[^|]*    # forget previously matched characters with \K, then match set of data containing the needle until the end of string or first encountered pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern which seems to be working:

```
(?<=\||^)((?:(?!\|).)*Interface123.*?)(?=\||$)
```

This uses tempered dots to match the segment of the string you want, containing `Interface123`.  Here is a brief explanation:

```
(?<=\||^)       assert that what is prior is either pipe or the start of the string
((?:(?!\|).)*   consume anything so long is it is NOT pipe
Interface123.*? match 'Interface123` followed by anything up to
(?=\||$)        assert that what follows is either pipe or the end of the string
```

### Demo

This answer uses lookarounds, but based on your comment that your regex flavor is Perl compatible, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Needs to match the whole "segment" right? So that it doesn't match `Interface1234`.

Comment: I think OP wants to first find `Interface123`, then find a second occurrence with surrounding characters. It's quite unclear, but I'm pretty sure the answer the OP is looking for won't involve `Interface123` in the actual regex.

Comment: Yes you are right, it can be any interface. Regex should take everything from the start of string until "|ˇ and find where in another place of string beetween "|" apears that match

Comment: @Whit3H0rse I still think best practice here would be extract the value `Interface123` from the text using Perl (which should be very easy to do).  Once you have that value cached, then build your regex pattern using my answer as a template.

Comment: Grafana uses  only regex,  and that's all I have. If this was script than the answer is straightforward

Comment: Then maybe have a look at the MickMac answer.